# odd/even numbers Python giving me ALWAYS odd

Tags: python, if-statement

So I started practicing python recently and in this exercise I have make an if/else with odd/even numbers. I input a number and if its even I print "its even" else "its odd". I don't understand what is wrong with my code when I did exactly the same thing than the correct answer but saving it in a variable.

**I did this** the calc works but always gives me odd

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

even = number % 2 == 0

print(even)

if number == even:
    print("This is an even number.")
else:
    print("This is an odd number.")
```

**the solution was this**

```
if number % 2 == 0:
  print("This is an even number."
else:
  print("This is an odd number."
```

Comment: Where the code says `print(even)`, **what results** did you see it print? What do you think should happen, if you try to *compare* such a result to `number` (like `number == even`)? Why? In your own words, *what do you see as different* between what your code tries to do, and what the working code does?

Answer (score 3):

```
if number == even:
```

`number` is an integer, such as 1,2,3, etc.

`even` is a boolean true/false.

Of course those are not equal.  (Except for two special cases: false=0 and true=1)

Perhaps you meant to say this instead?

```
if even:
```

Comment: Just wanted to add a slight note: Python has quirks when it comes to integers and boolean values. It will treat any nonzero value as if it was `True`, but when it comes to comparing equality, `True` is in fact equal to `1` and `False` is equal to `0` (so, sometimes numbers and booleans will actually be equal when comparing them). Regardless, John is correct that you don't want to be comparing `number == even` here. `even` is a boolean variable that you defined earlier, while `number` is an integer. Comparing the two generally doesn't make sense.

Comment: @DancingBear I added the special case comparisons to my answer.

Comment: @DancingBear fundamentally, `isinstance(True, int)` is true, because `issubclass(bool, int)`

Answer (score 1):

Ah, but you *didn't* do the exact same thing.

You had this:

```
if number == even:
```

If you eliminate the `even` variable as in the working answer, that becomes this:

```
if number == (number % 2 == 0):
```

Which hopefully makes the difference clear.

Comment: I should be noted that `even = number % 2 == 0; number == even` is not equivalent to `number == number % 2 == 0` because of comparison chaining in python. so for example, `1 <= x <= 2` is actually equivalent to `1 <= x and x <= 2` (with `x` only being evaluated once). So `number == number % 2 == 0` is equivalent to `number == number % 2 and number  %2  == 0`

Comment: Good point, @juanpa.arrivillaga. Added parens to keep the equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe easier to grok if you choose `odd` instead:

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

odd = number % 2

print(odd)

if odd:
    print("This is an odd number.")
else:
    print("This is an even number.")
```